# Expression Engine paths/urls affecting CSS sprite navigation in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, url, navigation, expressionengine

I'm currently putting an HTML site into Expression Engine. The site uses the body ID tag to drive the sprite navigation rather than current/active classes. When I created the site index with blank links the navigation appeared correctly. However when I linked the pages to the appropriate templates the sprite positions all defaulted to the last sprite in the navigation's a:link position. When hovered the link would display properly and when clicked take me to the correct place and change to the correct a:focus/hover position. This behavior occurs in Firefox but not Safari. In Safari everything appears how I expected it to. 
I'm using Expression Engine 2.x on a local installation. I've re-examined the channel urls and the site config settings as well but I've run out of ideas as to what the problem could be. 
Any thoughts would be appreciated.

This is a [visual](http://anony.ws/di-0IZC.gif) of the issue I'm having. . The first line is what is how the nav appears in Firefox. The second row is how the link looks when a link is hovered over. The third is how the nav is rendered in Safari.

This is the css for the navigation:

```
/* navigation */
#nav    {
background: url("/img/nav-bg.gif") no-repeat top left;
position:absolute;
top:176px;
width:960px;
height:44px;
z-index:20;
}

ul#navlist {
position:relative;
height:35px;
width:512px;
padding-left:192px;
margin-top:4px;
overflow:hidden;
}


ul#navlist li   {
padding:0;
margin:0;
float:left;
margin:0px;
text-indent:-9999px;
list-style:none;
}

ul#navlist li a {
display:block;
background-image:url("/img/main-nav-sprite.jpg");
background-repeat:no-repeat;
overflow:hidden;
}

ul#navlist li a:link, #navlist a:visted {
display:block;
}

li#home a {
width:82px;
height:35px;
}

li#services a {
width:101px;
height:35px;
}

li#portfolio a {
width:105px;
height:35px;
}

li#blog a {
width:76px;
height:35px;
}

li#about a {
width:82px;
height:35px;
}

li#contact a {
width:65px;
height:35px;
}

li#home a:link, a:visited   {
background-position:0px 0px;
}

li#home a:hover, a:focus    {
background-position: 0px -35px;
}

li#services a:link, a:visited   {
background-position:-82px 0px;
}

li#services a:hover, a:focus    {
background-position: -82px -35px;
}

li#portfolio a:link, a:visited  {
background-position:-183px 0px;
}

li#portfolio a:hover, a:focus   {
background-position: -183px -35px;
}

li#blog a:link, a:visited   {
background-position:-288px 0px;
}

li#blog a:hover, a:focus    {
background-position: -288px -35px;
}

li#about a:link, a:visited  {
background-position:-364px 0px;
}

li#about a:hover, a:focus   {
background-position: -364px -35px;
}

li#contact a:link, a:visited    {
background-position:-447px 0px;
}

li#contact a:hover, a:focus {
background-position: -447px -35px;
}

/* Main Navigation Active States */
body#home-page ul#navlist li#home a {
background-position:0 -35px;
}

body#services-page ul#navlist li#services a {
background-position:-82px -35px;
}

body#folio-page ul#navlist li#portfolio a   {
background-position:-183px -35px;
}

body#blog-page ul#navlist li#blog a {
background-position:-288px -35px;
}

body#about-page ul#navlist li#about a   {
background-position:-364px -35px;
}

body#contact-page ul#navlist li#contact a   {
background-position:-447px -35px;
}
/* end */
```

This is my html nav code appended:

```
    <div id="nav">
    <ul id="navlist">
    <li id="portfolio"><a href="http://localhost:8888/portfolio" title="hue samples">portfolio</a></li>
    <li id="blog"><a href="http://localhost:8888/news" title="learn with us">blog</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- ***nav -->
```

I tried using {path="template group/template"} as well but the result was similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your CSS, you're declaring some of the same rules multiple times in your stylesheet. As a result, whatever rules appear later in the stylesheet will override any previous rules matching the same selector.

Therefore, you can greatly simplify your CSS by removing the unnecessary `:link`, `:visited`, et al [pseudo class selectors](http://css-tricks.com/5762-pseudo-class-selectors/) which will make debugging your image sprite much easier.

For example, consider the following HTML:

```
<div id="nav">
    <ul id="navlist">
        <li id="portfolio"><a href="#">portfolio</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The relevant CSS can be simplified and consolidated into:

```
li#portfolio a {
    background-position: -183px 0;
    height: 35px;
    width: 105px;
}

li#portfolio a:hover {
    background-position: -183px -35px;
}
```

Removing and eliminating the [LVHA](http://css-tricks.com/5762-pseudo-class-selectors/) (**L**O**V**E **HA**TE) pseudo classes from your CSS *where they're not needed* will drastically reduce the complexity debugging your problem.

Comment: I'll minimize the CSS and see how things go.

Comment: Hey, I just put my CSS on a diet as you suggested and my sprite is now behaving properly in EE! Thanks very much for that advice. I wouldn't have identified LVHA as the problem on my own.

Comment: You're quite welcome! If you're satisfied with my answer(s), be sure to vote it up and mark is as accepted. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Check to make sure that you're [linking to stylesheets](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/globals/stylesheet.html) correctly in your templates.

If your CSS is an ExpressionEngine template:

```
<link href="{stylesheet=template_group/template_name}" media="all" />
```

If your CSS is a file on your server:

```
<link href="{path=/css/screen.css}" media="all" />
```

With your stylesheet(s) linked to correctly, the only other possibility to your problem would be the path to your sprite from within the stylesheet.

I prefer to use absolute paths to images, so it makes maintenance easy:

```
#foo {
    background: url(/images/sprite.png) no-repeat left top;
}
```

To confirm your paths are correct, use whichever method is more comfortable for you and look for errors using:

- Firefox's Firebug
- Safari's Activity Monitor or WebKit Inspector
- Chrome's Developer Tools
- Apache's `error_log`.

*If you can post some code samples, it would make further troubleshooting your issue easier.*

Comment: My stylesheet seems fine - this is the code I used<br/> `code`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="{stylesheet='site/style'}" />`/code`.<br /> I had changed my image links to absolute paths early on.<br/> When my navigation code looks like this <br />`code` <ul id="navlist">
  <li id="about"><a href="#" title="about us">about</a></li>
  </ul>`/code` everything is visually fine.<br/> When I sub "#" with a url `code` "{path="template_group/template"}" `/code` the sprite appears as the last links up state. So instead of "about" I see "contact" in Firefox. On hover it's okay.

Comment: Do you have a URL you can share, or a jsFiddle showing the problem? *Note: Stack Overflw allos you to edit your question by updating it with more information after you've asked ... so you can add your code there instead of having it get clobbered in the comments.*

Comment: I added an image link since the site's bits and pieces are still living on my local machine. Thanks for the heads up on the updating the post feature, that's much easier.

Comment: It looks like your issue is strictly related to your CSS and not ExpressionEngine. Can you post the relevant CSS -- either appended to your question or preferably in a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)? *Also, have you considered simply using CSS3 properties combined with a @font-face rule instead of an image sprite?*

Comment: Prior to the EE implementation there were no sprite issues but I will post the css as maybe I'm not seeing something. I'm trying to implement the site with as little scripting as possible so I have stayed away from font matching tech..